# Send User email after creating a post, with Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a User model (with Devise), and a Post model that belongs to the user. I used [this railscast (pro)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised) to send the User an email after creating an account

I created a "NewPostMailer"

This is my mailer:

```
class NewPostMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "email@gmail.com"

  def new_post_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url = "http://localhost.com:3000/users/login"
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "New Post")
   end
end
```

My posts_controller:

```
  def create
    @post= Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @deal.save
        NewPostMailer.new_post_confirmation(@user).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
```

post.rb

```
  after_create :send_new_post_email

  private
  def send_new_post_email
    NewPostMailer.new_post_email(self).deliver
  end
```

What do I have to change to send the User an email after he creates a Post. Thanks.

Comment: The above code sends an email twice. Take the NewPostMailer call out of your controller action. Also, in your post.rb file make the parameter self.user, right now you are passing the post object not user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create another mailer (http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3)

```
 class YourMailerName < ActionMailer::Base
     default :from => "you@example.com"

   def post_email(user)
    mail(:to => "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Registered")
   end
 end
```

In your Post model

```
 after_create :send_email

 def send_email
   YourMailerName.post_email(self.user).deliver
 end
```

Sending an email is very slow so think about putting this in a background job.

Comment: Do I need to add something to my posts_controller?

Comment: No you dont have to, check my comments on your question. The after_create callback in your model will be called after your create action runs.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a fairly similar method to do this. First, create an `after_create` [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) in your `Post` model, with something like:

```
after_create :send_user_notification

def send_user_notification
  UserMailer.post_creation_notification(user).deliver
end
```

You will need to make sure that there is a relationship between the user and the post, and create the `post_creation_notification` method in your `UserMailer`, the same way you made your old one. It might also be worth pointing out that just blindly firing off emails like this isn't necessarily the best way to do this. Not only does it add extra unnecessary time to a request, but it also doesn't fail in a gracefully recoverable fashion. You may wish to explore adding the emails to be sent to a queue ([like this, for example](https://code.google.com/p/mail-queue/))  to be processed, with a cron job or something, if the site you are creating will see anything other than very light usage.