# Send email after attribute updated Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to send an email to a user once the status of their pdform is updated. I already have some stuff written out on how I want this done.

In my `pdform.rb` model

```
after_update :sendemail

def sendemail
  if status_changed?

  end
end
```

I already have emails being sent out when the user creates a new form, however, I am not sure how to send an email in the model.

The controller has this mailer function that works correctly. How could I send this in this model?

```
NewPdform.notify_user(current_user, @pdform).deliver
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Still getting the hang of ActiveRecord.

#### Update:

In my pdforms_controller update method I have added the following variable.

```
update_user = @pdform.user
```

I added an attr_accessor in `pdform.rb` (the model)

```
attr_accessor :update_user
after_update :sendemail

def sendemail
  NewPdform.notify_update(update_user).deliver
end
```

And in my mailer

```
def notify_update(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: "some change occured")
end
```

Comment: http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2009/11/16/sending-email-controllers-versus-models

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13755360/2968762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own issue after using my brain more extensively.

In the call to the mailer function instead of passing the parameter of `pdform`, which is the name of the class anyways, just pass `self`.

```
def sendemail
  NewPdform.notify_update(self).deliver
end
```